# Add to Values in An Array in a CSV File

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I imported my CSV File and made the data into an array. Now I was wondering, what can I do so that I'm able to print a specific value in the array? For instance if I wanted the value in the 2nd row, 2nd column. 
Also how would I go about adding the two values together? Thanks.

```
import csv
import numpy as np
f = open("Test.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
    print(np.array(row))
f.close()
```

Comment: You realise you aren't actually keeping any of that data, right? Why not use e.g. [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)?

Comment: Code doesn't show any idea. Better provide example values instead of just asking questions.

Comment: My code does actually show data from the imported CSV File so get your facts straight first...

Comment: It *shows* it, but doesn#'t *store* it; after each loop, the data is discarded. I believe @wenzul's point was that you appear to have made no effort to implement anything beyond that yourself.

Comment: I have managed to edit my code so that I can choose specific values from the array but I want to know what to do to add them

Comment: I think it' non-constructive to use numpy for your requirement. May start learning python with open a csv files and print lines. Go on `import csv` and print a `row` and then go for specific columns and rows.

Comment: were you able to receive an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use csv module.

This code reads csv file and prints value of cell in second row and second column. I am assuming that fields are separated by commas.

```
with open("Test.csv") as fo:
    table = [row.split(",") for row in fo.read().replace("\r", "").split("\n")]
print table[1][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I grabbed a dataset ("Company Funding Records") from [here](https://support.spatialkey.com/spatialkey-sample-csv-data/).  Then, I just rewrote a little...

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
#import numpy as np

csvaslist = []

f = open("TechCrunchcontinentalUSA.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
#    print(np.array(row))
    csvaslist.append(row)
f.close()

#  Now your data is in a dict.  Everything past this point is just playing
#  Add together a couple of arbitrary values...
print int(csvaslist[2][7]) + int(csvaslist[11][7])

#  Add using a conditional...
print "\nNow let's see what Facebook has received..."
fbsum = 0
for sublist in csvaslist:
    if sublist[0] == "facebook":
        print sublist
        fbsum += int(sublist[7])
print "Facebook has received", fbsum
```

I've commented lines at a couple points to show what's being used and what was unneeded.  Notice at the end that referring to a particular datapoint is simply a matter of referencing what is, effectively, original_csv_file[line_number][field_on_that_line], and then recasting as int, float, whatever you need.  This is because the csv file has been changed to a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

To get specific values within your array/file, and add together:

```
import csv

f = open("Test.csv")
csv_f = list(csv.reader(f))

#returns the value in the second row, second column of your file
print csv_f[1][1]

#returns sum of two specific values (in this example, value of second row, second column and value of first row, first column
sum = int(csv_f[1][1]) + int(csv_f[0][0])
print sum
```